# rspec at_least once using with condition not working as I would expect

Tags: rspec

Is there a way to test that a method gets called at least once with an argument matcher if the method is called other times with a different argument.  Here's an example:

```
class A
  def test(a)
    puts "AAA"
  end
end

it "should work" do
  a = A.new
  expect(a).to receive(:test).with(1).at_least(:once)
  a.test 2
  a.test 1
  a.test 3
end
```

I'm just concerned that test is called at least once with a certain param, but I get an expectation failure the first time that test is called with an argument that doesn't match.

**UPDATE**
A better example of what I'm wanting to do is a little more complex than this...I want to do custom matching against the params...something more like

```
it "should work" do
  a = A.new
  expect(a).to receive(:test).at_least(:once).with(an_instance_of(Fixnum)) do |i|
    expect(i).to be > 2
  end
  a.test 2
  a.test 1
  a.test 3
end
```

When I used mocha in the past the, you could pass a block to the with method to evaluate the params.  If the block returned false then the param expectation failed.  It seems that rspec only lets you inspect the params using the return block (which gets ignored when you use and_call_original).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `as_null_object` to basically ignore the calls with other parameters.

Change the line:

```
a = A.new
```

To:

```
a = A.new.as_null_object
```

Comment: That does work, but it causes the Object to turn into a full mock object.  This means that I can no longer use and_call_original on it.  Also, the docs say that it only works with should syntax enabled.

Comment: one more thing, this doesn't work if I want to use a more complicated expectation on arguments that are passed in...see my update to the original post.